# REST service, how to ensure method executed?

Tags: rest, http, soap

I am looking into how REST handles method calls, but im not sure if i'm right about the following:

If someone executes the method that inserts a new row in the database, can he ensure it is successfully executed or it failed? What if he did not receive the response that it failed because of internet failure?

Can the following situation happen with REST? And could SOAP be better to ensure failures like this?:

- USER_A -> www.example.com/row/foo (POST)
- SERVER -> successfully inserts row foo in database -> Sends response back
- USER_A internet failed, did'nt receive response
- USER_A handles error -> retries to insert foo
- SERVER -> successfully inserts row foo in database -> Sends response back
- USER_A receives succes response (But now foo is inserted twice)

Comment: There is a REST "pattern" of sending an empty POST request to create the resource and use the returned URI to update the state of the resource via idempotent PUT method (similar as explained [in the second half of this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584303/rest-api-and-uuid/31585837#31585837)). If the initial post request failed to return a URL within a predefined amount of time, the client can resend its empty POST request. If just the reply got lost, the server has just a furter empty resource, which can be cleaned by a back-process as some later point

Comment: Thank you! this was the information I needed

Comment: As SOAP can also use HTTP as transfer protocol, is a situation as described in the main post also a problem with SOAP?

Comment: Messages created via HTTP POST do not create new resources on the server side but invoke and execute certain methods. Here, you have similar issues like REST services when dealing with reliable invocations and responses. Reliable messaging with SOAP is therefore often solved by utilizing JMS/message queuing or via usage of [web service reliable messaging specification (WS-RM)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Reliable_Messaging). [This article](https://myarch.com/reliability-of-soap-over-http-web-services/) provides a good introduction to the topic